# How to search into hasMany relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model of Company and Dispensary

```
<?php 
// Company.php

public function dispensary() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(Dispensary::class);
}

// Dispensary.php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

What I want is first get the dispensary of the company which the user belongs.

```
$auth = \Auth::user();
$userCompany = $auth->company()->get();

$dispensaries = Company::find($userCompany->first()->id)->dispensary;
```

How should I construct a query where the user can search for the dispensary list where the user belongs.

I have tried using whereHas but it's searching from the Company instead of the Dispensary

```
Company::find($userCompany->first()->id)
    ->whereHas('dispensary', function ($query) use ($name) {
       $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%");
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally made it to work just by using where clause

```
$company = Company::find($id)->dispensary()
        ->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
        ->where('contact_email', 'like', "%{$email}%")
        ->get();
```